# how i can change the discord scopes next auth v5

Tags: typescript, next.js, next-auth

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyv75.png)
I need to change the scope, remove the email and add guilds, but I couldn't do that, researching I found a way to do it but it didn't work? Does anyone know how I can change the scopes?

I had been trying to do it this way.

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import Discord from "next-auth/providers/discord"
import type { NextAuthConfig } from "next-auth"

export const config = {
  theme: {
    logo: "https://next-auth.js.org/img/logo/logo-sm.png",
  },
  providers: [
    Discord({ clientId: "1183095707033403462", clientSecret: "HQAtuIRXhgl3sH3oW9cNYXgX8VmOO82N", authorization: { params: { scope: 'identify guilds' } }
   })
  ],
  callbacks: {
    authorized({ request, auth }) {
      const { pathname } = request.nextUrl
      if (pathname === "/middleware-example") return !!auth
      return true
    },
  },
} satisfies NextAuthConfig

export const { handlers, auth, signIn, signOut } = NextAuth(config)
```

It doesn't work that way :(